# Scrape tag input in a form using WinHTTP

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, winhttp

I have overcome by myself connection problem using `WinHTTP` (it was an error with `Debug.Print` of the response text method).

So I have to take a lot of value from a form ( over 20) and then create a string and pass it to `http://exampletry.it/visualizzaelenco.do` in order to generate a PDF file.

It's a sample of the form code.

```
<BODY>
<form name="trattamentoForm" method="post" action="/ecportal/trattamento_dettaglio.do">
<input type="hidden" name="service" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="ufficioLoggato" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="uff_comp" value="DZT">
<input type="hidden" name="profiloUtente" value="U">
<input type="hidden" name="tipoModelloRicerca.codice" value="V">
<input type="hidden" name="tipoModelloRicerca.descrizioneEstesa" value="V - MODELLO V">
<input type="hidden" name="partRicerca" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="annoRicerca" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="codiceRicerca" value="123456789">
<input type="hidden" name="dataPresRicerca" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="numProtRicerca" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="concessionarioRicerca.codice" value="">
......
```

So how can I get  the name and value without using tagname? I'm using WinHTTP and I don't want to use IE or other web browser. (I just able to do this using `.click` and VBA and IE)

ADDED CODE

```
oHtml.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
If http.Status = 200 Then




    Set OSTREAM = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      OSTREAM.Open
     OSTREAM.Type = 1
      OSTREAM.Write http.responseBody
      File1 = "E:\test.html"
      OSTREAM.SaveToFile File1, 2
          OSTREAM.Close
      End If
        Dim html As HTMLDocument
        Set html = GetHTMLFileContent("E:\test.html")

        Dim list As Object, i As Long
        Set list = html.querySelectorAll("trattamentoForm")
        For i = 0 To list.length - 1
            Debug.Print "Name: " & list.Item(i).Name, "Value: " & list.Item(i).Value



        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will admit to being unclear as to what you are trying to do. Assuming you are after the attributes `value` and `name` from the input tagged elements within the form you can use a CSS selector to target the all the form elements with a name attribute and read out the results matched elements name and value attribute values. Also, assumes each element has both name and value attributes (which appear to).

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", "yourURL", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim list As Object, i As Long
    Set list = html.querySelectorAll("form input[name]")
    For i = 0 To list.Length - 1
        Debug.Print "Name: " & list.item(i).NAME, "Value: " & list.item(i).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thks a lot! I used your code but i've received an error on GetHTMLFileContent ( sub or function not defined...) i added code in original post.

Comment: That is because it is a helper function for me to read from file. You should be using  the bottom example to populate your html. I will adjust.

Comment: graet... i add an "o" to html..my mistake...and delete name in form... so i have to get each "name" and "value" and create a string such as name1=value1&name2=value2&... to send in winhttp post request to "visualizzadettaglio.do" and generate the .pdf